# How do you append a column and drop a column with pandas dataframes? Can't figure out why it won't print the dataframe afterwards

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append

The `DataFrame` that I am working with has a `datetime` object that I changed to a `date` object. I attempted to append the `date` object to be the last column in the `DataFrame`. I also wanted to drop the `datetime` object column.

Both the append and drop operations don't work as expected. Nothing prints out afterwards. It should print the entire `DataFrame` (shortened it is long).

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df7=pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')
print(df7)
mydates = pd.to_datetime(df7['date']).dt.date
print(mydates)
df7.append(mydates)
df7.drop(['date'], axis=1)
print(df7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why drop/append? You can overwrite

`df7['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df7['date']).dt.date`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#   read csv, convert column type
df7=pd.read_csv('kc_house_data.csv')
df7['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df7['date']).dt.date

print(df7)
```

Comment: I didn't think you could do that. I guess it makes sense that it would be possible. I think this is the best answer because it eliminates the problem and solves the issue in a way that is likely faster because it does not append or drop,it just overwrites! Great idea!!!

Comment: Please try it out the solution and if it works for you, consider marking it as the 'accepted answer'. Would be happy to help if there's additional questions

Answer (score 0):

Drop a column using `df7.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)`.

Append a column using `df7['date'] = mydates`.